# Duplicate integers in array based on object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

What would be the best method to duplicate array integers based on key value from an API.

Input:
`{1208: "1", 1209: "2"}`

Output:
`[1208, 1209, 1209]`

So far I tried using Object.keys, however it only will return the parent key.

Comment: `Object.entries(inputObject).flatMap(([k, v]) => Array(+v).fill(+k))`

Comment: `Object.entries(obj).reduce((arr, [k, cnt]) => arr.concat(new Array(+cnt).fill(+k)), [])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over Object.entries.

```js
var obj = {1208: "1", 1209: "2"};
var arr = [];

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k,v]) => {

    for(let i=0;i<parseInt(v);i++){
        arr.push(k);
    }


});

console.log(arr);
```